# Pull pictures from folders on Google Drive and add them to a Sheet

Tags: javascript, time-limit-exceeded, google-apps-script

I have code that I have been using for 2 years and it was working perfectly until recently. It started to give a timeout warning a couple of weeks ago and now it's not really running anymore. The code pulls every picture from 13 different folders on google drive and then adds them to a sheet, it was giving the timeout warning after row 200. I modified it a bit but I'm still getting the exceeded maximum execution time warning (after 360 rows now)

I would really appreciate it if somebody had a solution for this. The script used to run pretty fast (around 2-3 rows per second), but now it's taking around 3-4 seconds per row. Thank you so much in advance!

Here's the script:

```
function Iteration() {
  var lista_carpetas = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("carpetas").getRange("A2:A").getValues(); //event list
  var lista_carpetas_ok = lista_carpetas.reduce(function(ar, e) {
    if (e[0]) ar.push(e[0])
    return ar;
  }, []); 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("data");
  sheet.clear()
  sheet.appendRow(["Name", "Date", "Size", "URL", "Download", "Description", "Image","Folder Id"]);

  for (var i = 5; i <8; i++) {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("data");
    var folderId = lista_carpetas_ok[i];
    var season1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("carpetas").getRange("B2:B").getValues(); //event list
  var season = season1.reduce(function(ar, e) {
    if (e[0]) ar.push(e[0])
    return ar;
  }, []);

 
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
    var contents = folder.getFiles();

    var cnt = 0;
    var file;

    while (contents.hasNext()) {
        var file = contents.next();
        cnt++;

        Logger.log(file);
        Logger.log(cnt);
// writes the various chunks to the spreadsheet- just delete anything you don't want
            data = [
                file.getName(),
                file.getDateCreated(),
                file.getSize(),
                file.getUrl(),
                "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=no_antivirus&id=" + file.getId(),
                file.getDescription(),
                "=image(\"https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=" + file.getId() +"\")",
                folderId,
            ];

            sheet.appendRow(data);
    };

  }
  
}
```